# Swift flatMap: How to remove only tuples from an array where specific element in the tuple is nil?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, optional-values

I have an array of tuples where the tuple contains some optional values:

`let arrayOfTuples: [(Int, String?, String?)] = ...`

How can I best remove from the array those tuples where the **second element** of the tuple is nil (no matter if the 3rd element is nil)?

When I use `flatMap` like

`let flatTuplesArray: [(Int, String, String)] = arrayOfTuples.flatMap({ ($0, $1, $2) })` then a tuple does not appear in the resulting `flatTuplesArray` if the **second or third element** of the tuple is nil.

I want to *apply* `flatMap` only on the first two elements of the tuple ($0 and $1) but the result array should still have tuples with three elements (and contain `""` for $2 nil values).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) on the second tuple element to either unwrap
it or have it removed (by the outer `flatMap`), and the nil-coalescing `??` on the third tuple element
to replace `nil` by an empty string:

```
let arrayOfTuples: [(Int, String?, String?)] = [(1, "a", "b"), (2, nil, "c"), (3, "d", nil)]

let flatTuplesArray = arrayOfTuples.flatMap {
    t in t.1.map { (t.0, $0, t.2 ?? "") }
}

print(flatTuplesArray)
// [(1, "a", "b"), (3, "d", "")]
```

If `t.1` is `nil` then `t.1.map {...}` evaluates to `nil` and is 
ignored by `flatMap`. Otherwise `t.1.map {...}` evaluates to the
value of the closure, with `$0` being the *unwrapped* second 
tuple element.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, `filter` can help you:

```
let arrayOfTuples: [(Int, String?, String?)] = [(1, nil, nil), (2, "", nil)]
let result = arrayOfTuples.filter({ $0.1 != nil })
print(result) // [(2, Optional(""), nil)]
```